# Best practice for calling function from another contract

Tags: solidity, delegatecall, interfaces, function

I'm a bit of a beginner so I'm sorry if I misphrase anything, but I haven't been able to find a definitive answer on this yet. I'm going through some tutorials which list out a few ways to call functions from another contract, but they specify that some are not recommended without specifying which are recommended. Here are the few ways that I've encountered so far.

- Using low-level call or delegatecall (not recommended, apparently)
- Copy pasting the other contract into your file and reference it almost like a class (this seems inefficient?)
- Creating an abstract contract or interface with the methods you need and then casting the deployed contract (to me, this seems like it might be the best route, it feels along the lines of best development practices - just not specific to solidity)